# Don't allow grandchildren of abstract classes to override their parent c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, design-patterns

```
// This class just offers a public interface for triggering events
public abstract class TriggerActivator
{
    public void ActivateTrigger(){
        OnTriggerActivate();
    }
    protected abstract void OnTriggerActivate();
}

// This class does some important work, but looks for specific information returned from its child
public abstract class RaycastTriggerActivator : TriggerActivator
{
    protected override void OnTriggerActivate()
    {
        // Do some important raycast-related stuff...
        bool specificImportantInfo = SpecifyImportantInfo();
        // Do some more stuff...
    }
    protected abstract bool SpecifyImportantInfo();
}

// This class basically gives the parent info it needs based on a specific input type
public class MouseRaycastTriggerActivator : RaycastTriggerActivator
{
    protected override bool SpecifyImportantInfo() => IsMouseButtonPressedDown();
}
// OR
public class ControllerRaycastTriggerActivator : RaycastTriggerActivator
{
    protected override bool SpecifyImportantInfo() => IsControllerButtonPressedDown();
}
```

BUT, someone could break this functionality easily:

```
public class MouseRaycastTriggerActivator : RaycastTriggerActivator
{
    protected override bool SpecifyImportantInfo() => IsMouseButtonPressedDown();

    /// It is important for this class's parent to implement this method,
    /// but now this class is hiding its parent's implementation
    protected override void OnTriggerActivate()
    {
        /// This guy can hide RaycastTriggerActivator's functionality
        /// and break the whole system
    }
}
```

I could see this happening if someone doesn't understand the system well enough, sees OnTriggerActivate in the list of available functions to override, and thinks that they need to use it.

**My question is**, if B : A, and A has an abstract method meant for B to implement, is there a way to hide that abstract method from C : B, if the method is specifically not meant for C to provide implementation for? (":" = "inherits from")

Am I worrying about this too much? I don't see how it could be a security risk for the entire program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the sealed keyword to prevent C from overriding the method implemented by B like so:

```
    public abstract class A
    {
        protected abstract void SomeFunction();
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        protected override sealed void SomeFunction()
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

now if you try to implement SomeFunction() in C like so:

```
public class C : B
    {
        protected override void SomeFunction()
        {
            //do something different
        }
    }
```

You'll receive an error in the IDE and you won't be able to compile:

> 'C.SomeFunction()': cannot override inherited member
>   'B.SomeFunction()' because it is sealed